# PHP: Prepare Watermark using ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Is there a way to create Video Watermark(Probably 30 Seconds Video) using `exec()`. I'm using Linux Server.

EDIT:

I searched through google, So, I'm able to convert the video using the following code.

```
exec("ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320x240 output.flv");
```

I believe there is something similar to crop the video as well.

Comment: Have you tried anything or followed any tutorials online that have pointed you in any direction?

Comment: Searching for ffmpeg watermark gives me a huge amount of hits that explain how to do it. Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, there is many thing I saw on different websites. But, they are all related to make an Image Watermark rather than a Video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using following command

```
exec("ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:30 -async 1 -strict -2 output.mp4");
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was searching for a long time. Thanks man, You solved my problem.